# Differences populating an associative array through $.ajax and $.get/$.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, associative-array

I tried to populate the global var `selectedDates` thought the first function but it fails when **I try to get some value, as for example, `selectedDates['1/23/2013']`**

After try with $.ajax instead $.get I can obtain values like `selectedDates['1/23/2013']`.

Where is the difference if both of them populates an outer var `the_selected_dates` which is returned to set `selectedDates`?

```
var selectedDates = {};
```

**function using `$.get` fails:**

```
function getSelectedDates_fails(lead_id, month) {
    var the_selected_dates = {};
    $.get(
            window.location.href,
            {
                gf_lm_ajax : 1,
                get : 'lead_reminder_get_dates',
                lead_id : lead_id,
                month : month,
                nonce_gf_lm_ajax : gf_lmJsVars.nonce_gf_lm_ajax

            },
    function(output) {
        $.each(output.reminders, function(n, val) {
            the_selected_dates[val.date] = val.date;
        });
    }, 'json');
    return the_selected_dates;
}
selectedDates = getSelectedDates_fails(35, 12); console.debug(selectedDates);
```

**debug data**

[image]

[image]

**function using `$.ajax` works:**

```
function getSelectedDates_works(lead_id, month) {
    var the_selected_dates = {};
    $.ajax(
            {
                url : window.location.href,
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    gf_lm_ajax : 1,
                    get : 'lead_reminder_get_dates',
                    lead_id : lead_id,
                    month : month,
                    nonce_gf_lm_ajax : gf_lmJsVars.nonce_gf_lm_ajax
                },
                async : false,
                success : function(output)
                {
                    $.each(output.reminders, function(n, val) {
                        the_selected_dates[val.date] = val.date;
                    });
                }
            });
    return the_selected_dates;
}
selectedDates = getSelectedDates_works(35, 12); console.debug(selectedDates);
```

**debug data**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using an object `{}` to simulate it.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous by default, your $.get does not finish before the empty `the_selected_dates` object is returned from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the data asynchronously, and make sure the ajax function is done when you decide to do something with the returned data :

```
function getSelectedDates(lead_id, month) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            gf_lm_ajax: 1,
            get: 'lead_reminder_get_dates',
            lead_id: lead_id,
            month: month,
            nonce_gf_lm_ajax: gf_lmJsVars.nonce_gf_lm_ajax
        }
    });
}

getSelectedDates(35, 12).done(function(output) {
    var the_selected_dates = {};
    $.each(output.reminders, function(n, val) {
        the_selected_dates[val.date] = val.date;
    });
    console.log(selectedDates);
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

While you are running `$.ajax` *synchronously*, `$.get` is not.

That's why `getSelectedDates_fails()` returns faster than you are getting a response from the server hence returning an empty object, `{}`.

What you are seeing in `selectedDates` is the state of the object before the request is completed *asynchronously*.

---

You can use [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to globally change the behavior of all `$.ajax` calls. But, I wouldn't recommend it for setting `async` to `false`.

Comment: It's true, but a better answer will explain what that means

Comment: @JuanMendes or possibly a link to one of the hundreds of questions that have this same problem

Comment: @alexander, JuanMendes, KevinB, Easy man. I had to test before accept one answer. And I gave one upvote  to all, as all point to the `synchronicity` aspect... Smile :)

Answer (score 2):

You have `aysnc: false` in your `$.ajax`, which is a setting you can't turn on with `$.get` directly -- you would have to use `$.ajaxSetup`.  Still, it's probably not something you want to do, but if the ajax request is running asynchronously, `return the_selected_dates;` is reached before the ajax request completes.  Instead, you would have to debug in the callback.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `async: false`, your success handler will run first before the main function returns; that's why it works. However, this is **not recommended** because it hangs your browser while it performs the call.

You should do it the asynch way, by passing a callback function into your `getSelectedDates_works()` function that gets called when the results have been processed. This way, the browser gets to "rest" in between the request and response.

```
function getSelectedDates_works(lead_id, month, cb) 
{
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(output) {
            var the_selected_dates = [];
            $.each(output.reminders, function(n, val) {
                 the_selected_dates[val.date] = val.date;
            });
            // perform callback
            cb(the_selected_dates);
        }
    });
}

getSelectedDates_works(123, 456, function(dates) {
    // do stuff with dates here
});
```